# C# serialize element with multiple element names?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am working on a project for a client which involves connecting to an API, and using the data that it returns. The API can't be changed since a lot of existing systems rely on it.

Here's the issue. One of the XML tags (Category) have several subcategories. But the wrapping tag that specifies the categories is named something different every level.

Here's an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Response>
    <Category>
        <ID>Some ID</ID>
        <Name>Some name</Name>
        <SubCatLevel2> <!-- This is a category tag - notice how it is named differently. -->
            <Category>
                <ID>Some ID</ID>
                <Name>Some name</Name>
                <SubCatLevel3> <!-- This is a category tag - notice how it is named differently. -->
                    <Category>
                        <ID>Some ID</ID>
                        <Name>Some name</Name>
                        <SubCatLevel4> <!-- This is a category tag - notice how it is named differently. -->
                            <Category>
                                <ID>Some ID</ID>
                                <Name>Some name</Name>
                            </Category>
                        </SubCatLevel4>
                    </Category>
                    <Category>
                        <ID>Some ID</ID>
                        <Name>Some name</Name>
                        <SubCatLevel4> <!-- This is a category tag - notice how it is named differently. -->
                            <Category>
                                <ID>Some ID</ID>
                                <Name>Some name</Name>
                            </Category>
                        </SubCatLevel4>
                    </Category>
                </SubCatLevel3>
            </Category>
        </SubCatLevel2>
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>Trailere</Name>
        <ToolCount>1</ToolCount>
        <SubCatLevel2/>
    </Category>
</Response>
```

So the question is - how can I (with an `XmlSerializer`) deserialize this XML through the use of attributes? I want the category to have a list of subcategories, knowing that the maximum depth of a category tree is 4, and that the possible element names of it are "SubCatLevel1", "SubCatLevel2", "SubCatLevel3" and "SubCatLevel4".

**Edit**
Would I be able to use `XmlAnyElementAttribute` somehow?